# Copy DataGridView contents to clipboard

Tags: c#, datagridview, copy, clipboard

I want to copy the contents of a DataGridView and paste it in Excel. I tried:

```
myDataGrid.SelectAll();
DataObject dataObj = myDataGrid.GetClipboardContent();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj, true)
```

But this just pastes nothing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you added this line?

```
myDataGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText;
```

Take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dec5efh1.aspx) for a working sample.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Microsoft Visual Studio You can do it in Design File. Your Gridview **->right Click->Propeties->ClipBoard Copy Mode->EnableWithoutHeaderText**