# cannot copy paste from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

I have a simple blank windows form as a test project
and a datagridview 
and a query to fill the datagridview

in this test project. I can highlight all the columns and rows

click CTRL + C

open excel

then click ctrl + V

and the data is there.

but on a program that I inherited from someone in the company
I have a similar data grid view. but I cannot copy paste

how can I identify what is the difference here? 
I check the data grid view properties for both test project and the program I inherited. both has the same following:
1. the read only = false
2. the copyclipboardmode = EnableWithAutoHeaderText

what else could prevent me from copy paste this value?

in the inherited program the only way to copy paste ist by double click the cell and copy, but. this limits me to copy one cell at a time , instead of multiple cell

please advise?

thank you

this is the code snippet from my test project

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {"TEST", "TEST2", "TEST3"})
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {"TEST", "TEST2", "TEST3"})
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {"TEST", "TEST2", "TEST3"})
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {"TEST", "TEST2", "TEST3"})
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {"TEST", "TEST2", "TEST3"})
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {"TEST", "TEST2", "TEST3"})
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {"TEST", "TEST2", "TEST3"})
End Sub
```

This is the frmForm.Designer.vb as requested by QuickDanger

```
    <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class frmForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.dgvSpecials = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
        Me.btnCreate = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.PartCode = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Me.PDF = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Me.SLDDRW = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Me.SLDPRT = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Me.BasePartCode = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Me.TEMPLATESLDDRW = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Me.TEMPLATESLDPRT = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Me.TEMPLATEDRWFILE = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Me.TEMPLATEPRTFILE = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Me.MakeSpecial = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
        CType(Me.dgvSpecials, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'dgvSpecials
        '
        Me.dgvSpecials.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
        Me.dgvSpecials.Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn() {Me.PartCode, Me.PDF, Me.SLDDRW, Me.SLDPRT, Me.BasePartCode, Me.TEMPLATESLDDRW, Me.TEMPLATESLDPRT, Me.TEMPLATEDRWFILE, Me.TEMPLATEPRTFILE, Me.MakeSpecial})
        Me.dgvSpecials.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Me.dgvSpecials.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.dgvSpecials.Name = "dgvSpecials"
        Me.dgvSpecials.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(917, 246)
        Me.dgvSpecials.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'btnCreate
        '
        Me.btnCreate.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom
        Me.btnCreate.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 246)
        Me.btnCreate.Name = "btnCreate"
        Me.btnCreate.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(917, 30)
        Me.btnCreate.TabIndex = 1
        Me.btnCreate.Text = "Create"
        Me.btnCreate.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'PartCode
        '
        Me.PartCode.HeaderText = "Part Code"
        Me.PartCode.Name = "PartCode"
        Me.PartCode.ReadOnly = True
        Me.PartCode.Width = 200
        '
        'PDF
        '
        Me.PDF.HeaderText = "PDF"
        Me.PDF.Name = "PDF"
        Me.PDF.ReadOnly = True
        '
        'SLDDRW
        '
        Me.SLDDRW.HeaderText = "SLDDRW"
        Me.SLDDRW.Name = "SLDDRW"
        Me.SLDDRW.ReadOnly = True
        '
        'SLDPRT
        '
        Me.SLDPRT.HeaderText = "SLDPRT"
        Me.SLDPRT.Name = "SLDPRT"
        Me.SLDPRT.ReadOnly = True
        '
        'BasePartCode
        '
        Me.BasePartCode.HeaderText = "Base Part"
        Me.BasePartCode.Name = "BasePartCode"
        Me.BasePartCode.ReadOnly = True
        '
        'TEMPLATESLDDRW
        '
        Me.TEMPLATESLDDRW.HeaderText = "DRW Template"
        Me.TEMPLATESLDDRW.Name = "TEMPLATESLDDRW"
        Me.TEMPLATESLDDRW.ReadOnly = True
        '
        'TEMPLATESLDPRT
        '
        Me.TEMPLATESLDPRT.HeaderText = "PRT Template"
        Me.TEMPLATESLDPRT.Name = "TEMPLATESLDPRT"
        '
        'TEMPLATEDRWFILE
        '
        Me.TEMPLATEDRWFILE.HeaderText = "Column1"
        Me.TEMPLATEDRWFILE.Name = "TEMPLATEDRWFILE"
        Me.TEMPLATEDRWFILE.ReadOnly = True
        Me.TEMPLATEDRWFILE.Visible = False
        '
        'TEMPLATEPRTFILE
        '
        Me.TEMPLATEPRTFILE.HeaderText = "Column1"
        Me.TEMPLATEPRTFILE.Name = "TEMPLATEPRTFILE"
        Me.TEMPLATEPRTFILE.ReadOnly = True
        Me.TEMPLATEPRTFILE.Visible = False
        '
        'MakeSpecial
        '
        Me.MakeSpecial.HeaderText = "MakeSpecial"
        Me.MakeSpecial.Name = "MakeSpecial"
        '
        'frmForm
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(917, 276)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.dgvSpecials)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnCreate)
        Me.Name = "frmForm"
        Me.Text = "frmForm"
        CType(Me.dgvSpecials, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents dgvSpecials As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
    Friend WithEvents btnCreate As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents PartCode As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents PDF As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents SLDDRW As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents SLDPRT As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents BasePartCode As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents TEMPLATESLDDRW As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents TEMPLATESLDPRT As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents TEMPLATEDRWFILE As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents TEMPLATEPRTFILE As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents MakeSpecial As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
End Class
```

Here is the actual frmForm.VB
SldWorks is member of SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks

```
Imports SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks

Public Class frmForm
    Dim App As SldWorks
    Public Sub Setup(App As SldWorks, Arr As ArrayList)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you try `WithoutAutoHeaderText` ? Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108872/copy-datagridview-contents-to-clipboard) thread?

Comment: Is the previous developer highjacking the Copy event somewhere else in code and then setting it to handled before the datagrid values can get sent to the clipboard?

Comment: no, copyclipboardmode properties are not set anywhere in the code. A new discovery I found is that. he did not databound the data grid view. but instead he just use datagridview.rows.add(New String() {PartCode, PDF, STRING1, STRING2}).

Comment: I made my test project using similar .rows.add(new String(){"TEST"}) and I am still able to copy paste on my test project. But not on the program I inherited.

Comment: I would say the Ctrl+C is handled somewhere...

Comment: Try posting frmForm.vb. If you don't want to post all the code, then post all the subs declaration rows... also find any **AddHandler** event handling declaration.

Comment: Believe it or not there is only two subs declaration in the form.vb

Comment: I posted the actual vb form (just the subs). That is all. no other declaration inside the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: this problem is due to solidWorks.Interop.sldworks and the application being in Solidworks environment

I've heard from other solidworks developers the ctrl C just refused to work

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you have to set `MultiSelect` property of the DataGridView to `true`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have set `ClipboardCopyMode` to `Disable`. Change this property to any other three available options.

Comment: copy clip board mode has been set to other than disable

Answer (score 1):

It looks like others have had success with `ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText`
(see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108872/copy-datagridview-contents-to-clipboard)). If that doesn't help, could you paste the designer code for the dataGridView? (it is found in the project file [formname].Designer.vb)

You might also want to search the code for references to this control, and verify that the original developer did not modify the `ClipboardCopyMode` property at run-time.

**Edit:** Since none of the suggestions seem to be working, you could "roll your own" version of copy/paste using a tab-delimited format:

Note: This copies all data, not just selected cells, but you can modify it to only do selected cells.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.C AndAlso e.Control Then
        Dim sb = New StringBuilder()

        ' If you want the headers, keep these two lines
        Dim headers = DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)()
        sb.AppendLine(String.Join(vbTab, headers.[Select](Function(column) Convert.ToString(column.HeaderText)).ToArray()))

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim cells = row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell)()
            sb.AppendLine(String.Join(vbTab, cells.[Select](Function(cell) Convert.ToString(cell.Value)).ToArray()))
        Next
        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(sb.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Searched the solution for ClipboardCopyMode and nothing comes up. I also added the code as requested on the original post. Thank you

Comment: Look at the SO question I linked. It looks like changing the Clipboard Copy Mode to "EnableWithoutHeaderText" solved it for those users. I've been able to do this without editing the Designer.vb file by right-clicking the DataGridView and selecting properties, scroll down to ClipboardCopyMode, and select the "EnableWithoutHeaderText" option. According to the designer.vb you posted, you've left it on the default "EnableWithAutoHeaderText", which is why it isn't showing in your designer file.

Comment: tried EnableWithoutHeaderText - I still cannot copy paste.

Answer (score 1):

Other developer use Ctrl+C for some shortcut key in his project.
If you can check his design,Please go through property of Menubar->ShortcutKeys

Answer (score 0):

For copying data from the datagridview, we are getting multiple errors. So, I have developed following code for my application for this purpose using the help of QuickDanger from the above .

```
   Private Sub grdDetails_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles grdDetails.KeyUp
    Try
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.C AndAlso e.Control Then
            Dim mGrid As DataGridView, mCol As DataGridViewColumn, mRow As DataGridViewRow, mCell As DataGridViewCell
            Dim mStrBld As New StringBuilder
            mGrid = CType(sender, DataGridView)
            ' Copying Header 
            For Each mCol In mGrid.Columns
                If mCol.HeaderText IsNot Nothing Then
                    mStrBld.Append(vbTab & mCol.HeaderText)
                Else
                    mStrBld.Append(vbTab & "")
                End If
            Next
            mStrBld.Append(vbCrLf)
            '  Copying Data
            If mGrid.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                'Display progress in Progress Bar if rows are more
                'ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0 : ProgressBar1.Value = 0 : ProgressBar1.Maximum = mGrid.Rows.Count : ProgressBar1.Step = 1 : ProgressBar1.Visible = True
                For Each mRow In mGrid.Rows
                    For Each mCell In mRow.Cells
                        If mCell IsNot Nothing AndAlso mCell.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                            mStrBld.Append(vbTab & mCell.Value.ToString)
                        Else
                            mStrBld.Append(vbTab & "")
                        End If
                    Next
                    mStrBld.Append(vbCrLf)
                    'ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
                Next
                ' sending data to clipboard, so we can safely past the same
                My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(mStrBld.ToString)
                'ProgressBar1.Visible = False
            Else
                MsgBox("No Data...1", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End If
        End If
            e.Handled = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error:" & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```